# VS Code - Is there a way you can make the Minimap bigger?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have enabled the MiniMap in Visual Studio Code **(VSCODE)** with the following code:
`"editor.minimap.enabled": true`

But can I make it bigger? It's so small at the right.

Comment: Are you wanting to change its font size or its width?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

thanks Alex there is a new setting from VSCode [release 1.40.0](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40#_minimap-scaling-and-improved-font-rendering) onwards:

```
"editor.minimap.scale": 2
```

before VSCode 1.40.0:
there is no zoom-level for the minimap.

But i think the following settings is useful as it renders it schematically which looks much nicer than with true! Maybe this improves it! ;-)

```
"editor.minimap.renderCharacters": false
```

Comment: It really looks better. The code blocks seem to be cleaner and pop out clearly instead of looking like squiggles!

Comment: From VS Code [v1.40.0](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40#_minimap-scaling-and-improved-font-rendering) a new configuration is introduced. Use `"editor.minimap.scale": 2,`

Answer (score 22):

In the settings, you can set the width with

```
// Limit the width of the minimap to render at most a certain number of columns
"editor.minimap.maxColumn": 120
```

Comment: this does not do anything sadly - i wrote 400 just to check it and the minimap size stays the same

Comment: this can make it only smaller :(

Comment: Awesome! I actually like to make it smaller to save some screen spaces. Setting maxColumn=60 is what I want. :)

Answer (score 6):

From vscode [release 1.40.0](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40#_minimap-scaling-and-improved-font-rendering)

```js
"editor.minimap.scale": 2,
```

Answer (score 6):

There are two new minimap settings which are in v1.43:

`Editor › Minimap: Size`

values: `proportional`, `fit` and `fill`

From https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_43.md#minimap-size:

> When set to `proportional` (the default), each line gets a certain
>   amount of vertical space in the minimap, depending on
>   `editor.minimap.scale`. For example, on a high-DPI monitor, with a
>   configured scale of 1 (the default), each line gets 4 px in the
>   minimap. So for a file of 100 lines, the height of the lines rendered
>   in the minimap is 400 px, and for a file of 1000 lines, it is 4000 px.
>   That means that for large files, the minimap will also scroll, as the
>   current file is scrolled.
>
> When set to `fit`, the height of the minimap
>   is limited to never be larger than the editor height. So if a file has
>   many lines, they will be sampled and only a subset will be rendered in
>   the minimap, such that there is no need for the minimap to scroll.
>
> When set to `fill`, the height of the minimap is always the editor
>   height. For large files, this is also achieved by sampling lines, but
>   for small files, this is achieved by reserving more vertical space for
>   each line (stretching the lines).

Here the size is changed from `proportional` to `fit`, and then in a smaller file, from `fit` to `fill`:

[image: minimap fill and fit]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted. For me, the minimap was throwing me off because it didn't line up with the scroll bar. "fit" solves this problem <3

Comment: Oh and further to this, I've found that I like "fill" even better! No scrolling on the minimap ever. Lines up perfectly with the scroll bar. Great when stuff is highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

Not yet, but the pull request is on its way https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/82265